# Disk size parsing with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have two file one has Disk and its size and another has file system and its required size info.

disk-info:

```
sda 40G
sdb 100G
sdc 100g
```

Fs-info:

```
/a  50G
/b  40G
```

so what I am looking for is based to total fs system size (40 +50)=90G how many disk I needed from disk-info list to use and print their name (in this case I need sda and sdb).

I tried:

```
awk '{sum+2} (NR%1==0) {if ( $sum -ge 90 ) {print $1} }' disk-info
```

But it is printing out all disk instead of only sda and sdb. Any help would be appreciated to fix this or with new code to achieve the goal.

Comment: In the light of your subject line, can you explain why you have given this question a Perl tag? Are Perl solutions acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to compute the sum of the second column from both files and output the minimum number of lines from `disk-info` such that the sum from `fs-info` is reached.

To do that, you could use something like this:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[gG]$/,"")}NR==FNR{fs+=$2;next}disk<fs{print $1}{disk+=$2}' fs-info disk-info
sda
sdb
```

- `sub` removes the "G"/"g" from the end of each line (of course, this assumes that all your sizes are in GB).
- For the first file (fs-info), a sum is taken of the second field. The condition `NR==FNR` only applies to the first file, where the total record number is equal to the record number for the current file.
- For the second file (disk-info), if `disk` is still lower than `fs`, the first field is printed.

Comment: It would be useful if you added your interpretation of the OP's question, and thereby described what your awk code does

Comment: @Borodin I have added my interpretation of the question (although admittedly, it was quite difficult to word clearly). I thought that my existing explanation of the code was adequate - was there anything in particular that was unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {sum=90} {if ( sum > 0 ) {sum-=$2; print $1} }' disk-info
```

result is:

```
sda
sdb
```

(a different subject is how to calculate the "90", but this part was also excluded in your original post, thus, I suppose you have already solved it).